# Changing the layout with slide transition animation?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-layout

I'm trying to change the layout in android like slide transition animation. How to do this? I've four layouts these four must change using buttons like slide transition animation also. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go this should help. you can use viewFilpper with slide andimaiton

here is a sample link
[using-view-flipper-in-android](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-view-flipper-in-android.html)

instead of those textview in the example you can put your 4 layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways,

1) Declare all your 4 activities in your manifest.XML and using Intent u can achieve using Intent

See this,

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/65.html

2) You can also use Viewflipper for this and as u r having 4 views u can use flipper.setDisplayChild() . see here

```
    ViewFlipper flipper;

private Animation inFromTopAnimation() {

Animation inFromTop = new TranslateAnimation(
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
);
inFromTop.setDuration(1000);
inFromTop.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
return inFromTop;
}
private Animation outToBottomAnimation() {
Animation outtoBottom = new TranslateAnimation(
  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f
);
outtoBottom.setDuration(1000);
outtoBottom.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
return outtoBottom;
}

private Animation outToTopAnimation() {
Animation inFromTop = new TranslateAnimation(
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
);
inFromTop.setDuration(1000);
inFromTop.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
return inFromTop;
}
private Animation outFromBottomAnimation() {
Animation outFromBottom = new TranslateAnimation(
  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f
);
outFromBottom.setDuration(1000);
outFromBottom.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
return outFromBottom;
}


       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

 flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

 Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

 Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.flipback);

 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
         flipper.setInAnimation(inFromTopAnimation());
         flipper.setOutAnimation(outToBottomAnimation());
         flipper.showNext();      
     }
 });

 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
         flipper.setInAnimation(outToTopAnimation());
         flipper.setOutAnimation(outFromBottomAnimation());
         flipper.showPrevious();

     }

 });
```